# Is output to HDMI via USB-C possible when the USB-C port does NOT output DP?

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Have seen a lot of conflicting information when trying to google this -- people claiming they did it successfully and others claiming it is impossible.

I have a laptop with USB-C out, but it does not support Thunderbolt, DP-altmode, or HDMI-altmode.

Does there exist a way to output to a HDMI monitor via this port?  Obviously it can't output direct video signal but I thought it might be possible for the display content to be just sent as data like any other data transfer and reassembled to HDMI by the hub. I understand this would not be a great refresh rate due to the lower bandwidth of the port.

If so, what should I look for in specifications of hubs to buy?

I got burned by buying a hub that seemed to claim this functionality but it didn't work, and contacting the manufacturer, they said it only worked on DP USB-C ports (which they didn't bother to mention in their specifications).

Comment: A simple (cheap) USB2/3 to HDMI adapter will do the trick if 1080p is all you need.  Also external USB3 hub with HDMI also good (for my use) as these also come with Ethernet and a ton of ports.  Avoid the ones that say 4K (you probably won't be able to support them).  I have had ones that suck and ones that work well.  I can/will not advise a brand.  Read the reviews.  I use the second screen for coding and see very little (if any) lag on an old crappy HP laptop.  The most you should spend is 20USD for the simple adapter so you have little to lose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a laptop with USB-C out, but it does not support Thunderbolt, DP-altmode, or HDMI-altmode.
> Does there exist a way to output to a HDMI monitor via this port?

Yes.

> If so, what should I look for in specifications of hubs to buy?

DisplayLink.

I don't know if there are other brands of USB graphics processor units but DisplayLink is certainly popular.  Make note this is Display***Link***, not Display***Port***, they are very different in spite of the similar name and function.  There are USB-C docks and adapters with DisplayLink GPUs in them to allow video over the USB protocol.  DisplayLink adapters/docks/whatever will not work without drivers which makes them unique from DisplayPort adapters.  Because they require drivers it means only certain operating systems are supported, as opposed to working on things like a Nintendo Switch where there's no ability to install drivers.

Most adapters from USB-C to HDMI rely on the host to supply a DisplayPort video signal to their USB-C port, and the adapter then converts this DisplayPort video protocol into the HDMI protocol.  DisplayLink is a different beast in that it is its own GPU, which is why it appears as a unique output in the operating system display settings.  You can have it be an extension to the desktop because it is a separate GPU, a protocol adapter can't do that.

As you noted in another answer a USB-A to HDMI adapter will work, and they work because there is a DisplayLink GPU inside.  This is not all that different than any USB-C adapter with DisplayLink.  The USB-A adapter may be the cheaper option because of economy of scale, like many things they are cheaper by the dozen and USB-C adapters would not be as popular.  There may be some more capable DisplayLink HDMI adapters specifically for USB-C that take advantage of the higher power and bandwidth that USB-C allows, I didn't look close enough at the product offerings to know.  Point is that you are not likely to be missing out by taking the route of using a USB-C to USB-A adapter then plugging in a DisplayLink cable, dock, or adapter.

Answer (score 0):

A technically correct answer (the best kind) - I have successfully managed this by getting a USB-A to HDMI adapter and plugging it into the USB-A output port of the USB-C hub whose HDMI port doesn't work.